# Put chars used two times in a variable is a gain of space?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

Related to [How the compiler manages the same char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258247/how-the-compiler-manages-the-same-char), create a variable which contains characters used at least two times in the code, is a gain of space?

Example:

```
wstrFile.find_last_of(L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
wstrFile.find_last_of(L"aefgh");
```

for the compiler: is the same or worst or better than

```
std::wstring wstrTemp = L"aefgh"
wstrFile.find_last_of(L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
wstrFile.find_last_of(wstrTemp);
```

In all cases, I will use "wstrTemp" further, its creation is needed.

**NOTE TO SOLUTION:**

Thanks to both answers.
In order to complete the answer for my question, the fact to put chars used at least two times will save space but it is totally painful/not useful to add char by char in the console, that was my main aim before this question.

Comment: Are you asking whether creating a variable to hold the value of `wstrTemp` is better than supplying a string literal at every point it would be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same constant string literal twice in the same compilation unit

```
 static const char greet[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
 std::cout << "hello";
 std::cout << "hello";
 const char* t = "hello";
 std::cout << t;
```

the compiler is able to perform some space optimizations (although it is not guaranteed it will do it). Some compilers can do this across the entire binary. In Visual Studio it is an optimization option, "String Pooling".

However, it only applies to constants.

```
static char greet[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
std::cout << "hello";
```

these two cannot overlap because one is mutable and the other is not. Consider:

```
const char greet[] = "hello";
char greeting[] = "hello";
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    std::cout << greet << greeting << "\n";
    greeting[0] = 'j';
}
```

This should output "hellohello" and then "hellojello". If the strings were pooled the second iteration would errantly print "jellojello".

So in general you don't have to worry about manually deduping strings, the compiler will usually do it for you in optimized builds.

This can easily be tested with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *a = "hello";
    const char *b = "hello";
    const char *c = "hello";
    char d[] = "hello";

    std::cout << "&a[0] = " << (void*)&a[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "&b[0] = " << (void*)&b[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "&c[0] = " << (void*)&c[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "&d[0] = " << (void*)&d[0] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/hNf29c

In the case of `d` we get a different address - d is mutable, so a copy has to be stored, and the address is of the stack location the literal is copied to.

Comment: The compiler ignores totally variables? Even if a variable is initialized and doesn't change until a long moment after? Obviously, between these two times, this variable will used but not changed. The compiler can't detect this?

Comment: It doesn't ignore variables, but storage of string constants is done in a specific segment of the executable, and the compiler is able to de-dupe those constants.

If you transfer a string constant to a std::wstring, it has to create a copy, so each wstring variable you copy it to will use additional *heap* memory to store an additional copy of the string.

Comment: But if you have `const char *a = "hello", *b = "hello", *c = "hello";` it only needs to store `hello` once in the text segment, so the cost of the above is only the cost of three pointers and not 3 copies of the text. (Assuming you are compiling with string pooling enabled)

Comment: But your program is not useful, because it makes people thing that the string literal "hello" is stored in two different places, when they are not. The variables are because one is stored in a static location, while d[] is a local object, and has to be constructed in the stack, and it will be constructed off the "hello" string literal because there's a guaranty that the string literal cannot be modified since it's stored in a read only location.

Comment: @José added a note at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In your very specific case, where you have stated that you "have to" create the `std::wstring wstrTemp`, then second choice will be faster, but not by much.

`std::string::find_last_of` accepts `const wchar_t*` strings. So if you call

`std::string::find_last_of` with a `const wchar_t*`, the only thing it has to do is call `wcslen` and then do it's work.

While if you pass an `const std::wstring&` object (which you are doing), `std::find_last_of` will already know the `buffer` location, and the `length` size. Therefore it will instantly do it's work. It doesn't have to create another std::string object.

As for the other question, if you use a string literal like `"hello"` in multiple places, the compiler, most of the times (if not always) will store the `"hello"` only once. But if they are different, even by a single char like `"hello2"`, the compiler cannot longer do that, because of the null terminator which is required.

If you have the following:

```
const char *ptr = "hello";
char temp[] = "hello";
```

First, both variables obviously have different memory address. But the string literal will, most of the times, point to same address.

What the compiler does to create "temp" is: first allocate enough space in the stack, and then copy from the static location where the string literal "hello" is stored, into the stack address. That's the only reason why those variables do not have the same address. But the string literals do.

based on @kfsone response, here's how it works

```
const char *a = "hello";
const char *b = "hello";
const char *c = "hello";
//char d[] = "hello";

// This is actually how d looks like in assembly.
char d[sizeof("hello")]; //SUB ESP, 6

// d is constructed from the string literal "hello"
memcpy(d, "hello", sizeof("hello"));

// the compiler does not call memcpy. most of the times, it will call
// the assembly MOVS instuction if they are big string literals, or just 
// MOV DWORD PTR ES:[EDI], DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]
// MOV WORD PTR ES:[EDI+4], WORD PTR DS:[ESI+4]
// if they are small.

// Where EDI is the stack address of "d" and ESI the address of the string literal "hello"
```

Comment: "then second choice will be faster, but not by much.". I'm reading your answers but, faster only for the compilation, it will be the same duration for these both methods once executed, right ?

Comment: When you pass a wchar_t* string to the function, it has to calculate it's length at runtime, even if it's a string literal. But it's usually very fast to do that. But the std::wstring has already the size in it (since it was calculated when you created the wstring and the length is stored in the object). So find_last_of doens't have to calculate it again. That's why I said it's faster if you must create the std::wstring object. All of that is done while your program is being executed, not at compile time. You seem to be new at stackoverflow, so don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.

Comment: Also it's especially for a gain of space. Because I haven't the same words used, but same letters, I won't use a `const wchar_t*` only for letters. But, with your answers (@kfsone also), I don't know if use until many position of chars in `wstrTemp` here, is better to gain space instead of `L'i'` or other example `L'a'`.